# Lost most data on SD card after moving it to another Android device

Tags: external-sd

I have videos and music on the SD card inside my Android Moto G5 phone. I wanted to watch some of those videos on my Android Lenovo A10-70F tablet. So, I turned off my phone, removed the SD card, and placed it into my tablet.

The tablet asked if I wanted to have the SD card only work on the tablet, or use it as portable storage. I selected the portable storage option, and the file browser immediately popped up. I was horrified to find that the SD card was reporting itself as only being 1% full, and the only data inside was in LOST.DIR and a single album in /music (which is the first album alphabetically in my collection).

Moving the SD card back to my phone hasn't changed anything. Have I really lost all my media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, probably the SD card was formatted.
Try to plug your SD Card to a PC with an adapter and browse the folders to see if files are still there. I suggest you to configure Windows to show hidden files; it can be done from **Folder Options**.

[image]

If nothing shows up, they were deleted from the SD. By the way, 
*if they have not been overwritten yet*, it's pretty easy to **recover** them.
Just use a data recover software such as [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)

If you want to try with Recuva follow those steps after downloading and installing it from the [official website](https://www.piriform.com/recuva).

1. From the Recuva wizard window, select **All Files** then **Next>**
   [image: Recuva first step]
2. Select **"In a specific location"**, then **Browse**, then select your SD Card from the list (usually F:)
   [image: Recuva second step]
3. Check the **"Enable Deep Scan"** box then click on **Start**
   [image: Recuva third step]

The process may take a long time, *depending on the PC's characteristics and the R/W speed of the SD card*. 
At the end of the process, you will be able to view and eventually **recover** files previously deleted from the SD Card.

*edit: I suggest you to try both scanning modes as, in some cases, **normal scan mode** finds some files that are not detected in **deep scan mode and** vice versa*

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good set of steps to perform. It's ridiculous that my data would be formatted - I'm hardly computer illiterate, and there was absolutely no warning that it would happen.